# Having Issues reading / parsing Xml doc

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

I have a Xml doc similar (edited for here) to this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>
        <configSections>
            <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
                <section name="WebApptNotificationService.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
            </sectionGroup>
        </configSections>
        <connectionStrings>
            removed for questions
        </connectionStrings>
            <startup> 
                    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
            </startup>
        <system.net>
            <mailSettings>
                <smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
                    <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="C:\test\"/>      
                </smtp>
            </mailSettings>
         <mailSettings>
                <smtp from="xxxxx@xxxxxx.com">
                    <network host="mail.xxxxxxxx.com" enableSsl="true" password="xxxxxx" port="xxx" userName="xx@xxxxxxxx.com"/>
                </smtp>
                    <smtp from="No.Reply@xxxxxxxxxx.org">
                <network host="1stmsmail.xxxx.local" enableSsl="true" password="xxxxxxx" port="587" userName="ouruser"/>
            </smtp>
        </mailSettings>
        </system.net>
        <applicationSettings>
            <WebApptNotificationService.Properties.Settings>
                <setting name="ConfirmationInterval" serializeAs="String">
                    <value>60000</value>
                </setting>
                <setting name="EmailFromName" serializeAs="String">
                    <value>Test</value>
                </setting>
                <setting name="EmailFromAddress" serializeAs="String">
                    <value>mobile@xxxxx.com</value>
                </setting>
                <setting name="DaysBeforeReminder" serializeAs="String">
                    <value>2</value>
                </setting>
                <setting name="MinTextMinute" serializeAs="String">
                    <value>480</value>
                </setting>
                <setting name="MaxTextMinute" serializeAs="String">
                    <value>1200</value>
                </setting>

            </WebApptNotificationService.Properties.Settings>
        </applicationSettings>
    </configuration>
```

I am trying to read the values for   using the following code:

```
    private string parseXML(string name)
        {
            string returnVal = string.Empty;
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = xmlFile.SettingXML;
            //returnVal = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName(name).ToString();
            XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//configuration//applicationSettings//WebApptNotificationService.Properties.Settings//setting");
            MessageBox.Show(node.ToString());
            //returnVal = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.Name.(x => x.Element("Author"));
            return returnVal;
        }

       Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            Dim xdoc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(FILENAME)
            Dim versions As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = xdoc.Descendants("Version")
            For Each version As XElement In versions
                For Each trunk As XElement In version.Elements("Trunk")
                    Console.WriteLine(CType(trunk, String))
                    ComboBox1.Items.Add(CType(trunk, String))
                Next trunk

                For Each xEle As XElement In version.Elements("Branch")
                    Console.WriteLine(CType(xEle, String))
                    ComboBox2.Items.Add(CType(xEle, String))
                Next xEle
            Next version

        End Sub
```

Now xmlFile.SettingXML is a class that is created from a config file.  It is stored as a class.  I want to get the values from the settings name, based on the name passed in.  It appears though as if I am failing miserably.  If someone could please point me to the correct way to handle this it would be very much appreciated.

Edit: Failing miserably as was pointed out doesn't describe this issue.  Right now I am getting System.Xml.XmlElement in the Messagebox.

Comment: It seems you have a `Settings.settings` file under `Properties` folder in your project. Why not useing it?

Comment: Yes *failing miserably* is a very descriptive problem definition

Comment: Reza Aghaei, I am reading a config file that is not part of the project.

Comment: [ConfigurationManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I considered that, however I will also need to read the mail settings as well.  Also keep in mind the Xml file is foreign to the application.  The application will read values and move them to a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say `Right now I am getting System.Xml.XmlElement in the Messagebox` try  use `MessageBox.Show(node.InnerText)` this wil get the inner text of the `settings` element (node object). If you display your `node` object in the message box it will call the ToString method on the object whits is `System.Xml.XmlElement`.

Whit [XDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx) you easily can do this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string value = ParseXML("EmailFromAddress");
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }

    private static string ParseXML(string name)
    {
        // Load Document use 'XDocument.Parse' if you want to load the document from string
        XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("C:\\t\\2.txt");

        // Select element setting where name attribute is equal to name
        var node = xmlDoc
            .Descendants("WebApptNotificationService.Properties.Settings")
            .Elements("setting")
            .FirstOrDefault(x => (string) x.Attribute("name") == name);

        return node.Value;
    }
```